# Save every scraped element in a loop to a json file

Tags: python, json, loops, web-scraping

I am web scraping one website. When I scrape one URL, I write it to a dict. What I want to do is to write every dictionary to a json file. When I do the following loop, the file is saved as not a list, but as this structure {} {} that is not readable.

```
df_price_m = {}    
with open(r"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\diploma\information.json", 'w', encoding='utf8') as fout:
        row = 0
        for url in data:
            row +=1
            driver.get(url)
            user_name_xpath = "//h1[@itemprop='name' and @data-shmid='profilePrepName']"
            user_name = get_elements(user_name_xpath)    
            user_about_xpath = "//*[@class='desktop-profile-page__about-text']" 
            user_about = get_elements(user_about_xpath)
            df_info['id'] = url
            df_info['user_name'] = user_name[0]
            df_info['user_about'] = user_about[0]
            json.dump(df_price_m, fout, ensure_ascii=False)
```

I get the folowing json:

```
{"id": "www.aina.com", user_name: "Aina Nurma", "user_about": "I am a student"}
{"id": "www.aina.ru", user_name: "Aina Nur", "user_about": "I am a teacher"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing some code but I'd suggest saving all of data as a list of dicts and then dumping it at the end rather than dumping to file having processed just one url

Comment: Please put this as a comment.